# Asking For MYSQL assistance with a temp table

Tags: mysql

I am taking a class at Udemy.com.  I asked this question to the instructors already (3 days ago) but they are not being responsive and I am hoping to get the answer here.

I create a temp table successfully.  When I try to query against the table, I just created, I get an error saying the table does not exist.

My only question is why can I not query against the temp table I just created?  Where am I going wrong?

## this drops the table (if it exists) and creates the temp table

```
drop temporary table if exists activeUsers;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE activeUsers
SELECT
    c.*,
    a.phone
FROM
    customer c
        JOIN address a ON c.address_id = a.address_id
WHERE c.active = 1
GROUP BY 1;
```

This drops and then creates the temp table successfully and creates 584 rows but I am unable to query against it.

If I run `SELECT * from activeUsers`;
 it generates an error saying the temp table doesn't exist. Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you,

Rick

Comment: How are you querying the database? If you create the table in one session, then close the session and query in another session, you have just found out why it's called `TEMPORARY`. :)

Comment: a temporary table only exists within the connection you create it.

Comment: Formatting was lost here.  1st line is the drop statement.  Next line is the CREATE TEMP TABLE.  Line 3 is the select statement.  Line 4 is the FROM Statement.  Line 5 is an indented JOIN statement. Line 6 is the WHERE clause.  Line 7 is the GROUP BY.

Comment: If I run the select statement without the DROP and CREATE TEMP TABLE it runs fine.  Provides this message - Query Run Time: 0.133 sec.  Rows: 584

Comment: Are you doing this in phpMyAdmin? Like all PHP applications, a request to phpMyAdmin opens and closes a new session, and session-scoped things like temp tables do not survive to the next request. So the temp table is cleaned up as soon as you create it.

Comment: Amadan is 100% correct. We cannot answer your question if you won’t tell us how you run your queries (phpmyadmin? Php? Other language? Php command line command?) All commands need to be within the same session.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the SELECT statement alone does it return any data ?

If Yes, please check the Action Output log in the bottom to see whether CREATE Temporary table is successful..

Comment: 1. I am querying in the same session immediately after I perform the CREATE TEMP TABLE using MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  1. I am querying in the same session immediately after I perform the CREATE TEMP TABLE using MySQL.  2. If I run from just the SELECT Statement down, it returns the same number of rows as it tells me it creates when it creates the temp table.  That is why I am stumped.  It appears to work as expected but tells me the table that I just created doesn't exist.   - I didn't find a way or I would have attached screenshots.